# Is the coordinate-wise median equal to the geometric median if we apply a random rotation and average?

Tags: random-variables, rotations, median

There are multiple ways to extend the median to higher dimensions.

One natural way is to compute the coordinate-wise median, but this is *not* rotation-invariant. The coordinate-wise median is equivalent to computing $\underset{v \in \mathbb{R}^d}{\mathrm{argmin}} \sum_i^d \|x_i - v\|_1$. I.e., we are using the ell-1 geometry.

The [geometric median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median) is given by $\underset{v \in \mathbb{R}^d}{\mathrm{argmin}} \sum_i^d \|x_i - v\|_2$. Since this is definied in the ell-2 geometry, it is rotation invariant.

My question is about relating these two approaches. Specifically, let's force the coordinate-wise median to be rotation invariant by first randomly rotating the data before taking the coordinate-wise median and then undoing the rotation. This gives a randomized function. We can look at the expected value; that gives a deterministic function. Is this the geometric median? Beyond the expectation, we also would like some kind of bound on the variance.

Here's a more precise statement of the question.

> Define two functions $f : (\mathbb{R}^d)^n \to \mathbb{R}^d$ and $g : (\mathbb{R}^d)^n \to \mathbb{R}$ as follows.
>
> Let $x_1, \cdots, x_n \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $x=(x_1, \cdots, x_n)$. Let $U \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ be a uniformly random unitary matrix -- i.e. $\mathbb{P}[U^TU=I]=1$ and the distribution of $Uv$ is the same for all unit vectors $v \in \mathbb{R}^d$.
> Define $y_U := \underset{v \in \mathbb{R}^d}{\mathrm{argmin}} \sum_i^n \|U(x_i-v)\|_1$ to be the coordinate-wise median of the points in the rotated geometry. (For simplicity, we can assume $n$ is odd so that the argmin is unique. If $n$ is even, we take the mean of the two points in the middle, as usual.) Now define $f(x) := \mathbb{E}_U[y_U]$ and $g(x) = \mathbb{E}_U[\|y_U-f(x)\|_2^2]$.
>
> **Question 1:** Is $f(x) \in \underset{v \in \mathbb{R}^d}{\mathrm{argmin}} \sum_i^n \|x_i-v\|_2$? If not, is there some simpler expression for $f(x)$?
>
> **Question 2:** Is there a "nice" upper bound on $g(x)$? E.g., an upper bound in terms of $\sum_{i,j}^n \|x_i-x_j\|_2^2$

The expectation of the rotated objective function is the desired objective function. I.e. $$\forall x~\forall v ~~~ \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_i^n \|U(x_i-v)\|_1\right] \propto \sum_i^n \|x_i-v\|_2.$$ Unfortunately, we need the argmin inside the expectation, so this equation does not answer the question, but it indicates why it is reasonable to conjecture a positive answer to question 1.

Comment: I believe for d=2, n=3 the f(x) is the Hofstadter zero-point (X(360) [here](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html)) since it has barycentric coordinates proportional to the angles of the triangle, while the geometric mean is not (it is the Fermat point, either X(13) or one of the vertices, depending on whether one of the angles is above 120 degrees).

Comment: Have you made progress on this ?